# MySQL select if exists but show value with no if it doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a simple query like the following:

```
SELECT * from foo WHERE id IN (ids)
```

Say I pass the ids `1,2,3` and id `1` and `2` exist and `3` does not. How do I write this query so that 3 rows still show up, but a value of 'yes' shows up for 1 and 2, and a 'no' for 3?

My query would only return data for records with id 1 and 2, but I want it to show up for every id I pass in, but signify the ones that aren't in the table with a simple 'no'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to create a relation containing all the IDs and then left join `foo` on the IDs. In a `CASE` you can then check for the ID from `foo` being `NULL` and output `'no'` if it is, `'yes'` otherwise.

```
SELECT x.id,
       CASE
         WHEN f.id IS NULL THEN
           'no'
         ELSE
           'yes'
       END yesorno
       FROM (SELECT 1 id
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 2 id
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 3 id) x
            LEFT JOIN foo f
                      ON f.id = x.id;
```